# Properties of distribution of zeros of polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Polynomial $p_n(z) = (1 + \frac{z}{n})^n - 1$ has a property that all its zeros lie on the circle of radius $n$. It is easy to see because $$\frac{z}{n} = e^{\frac{i2\pi k}{n}} - 1$$

So we can "fit" zeros of polynomials of degree $n$ on the curve of degree $2$ (circle). Is it possible to do similar things i.e. find the curve of smaller than $n$ order where all zeros are placed, with the polynomial $$q_n(z) = \sum^n_{k = o}\frac{z^k}{k!} - 1$$

As both $p_n(z)$ and $q_n(z)$ $\to$ $e^z - 1$ as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no known explicit formula for the curve(s) on which the zeros of $q_n(z)$ lie.  They can be approximated, however.

Since most of the zeros travel outward to infinity at a rate of $\approx n$, it's common to scale them by $1/n$.  This means we are now looking at the zeros of the polynomial $Q_n(z) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} q_n(nz)$.

The zeros of $Q_n(z)$ accumulate on a set of curves in the complex plane.  These curves are:

- the circle $|z| = 1/e$ in the left half-plane ($\operatorname{Re} z < 0$),
- the segment of the imaginary axis $[-i/e,i/e]$, and
- the curve $|ze^{1-z}| = 1$ in the right half-plane ($\operatorname{Re} z > 0$).

See, for instance, [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/4329/21917).

It is also possible to find better approximations to the curves on which the zeros lie.  See, for example, the method in the paper by Carpenter, Varga, and Waldvogel *Asymptotics for the zeros of the partial sums of $e^z$, I.*  In particular, the sections where they calculate the curves $D_n$.  Though this curve is specifically for the zeros of the polynomials $Q_n(z)+1$, it should still yield a good approximation for the zeros of $Q_n(z)$ in the right half-plane.

The paper is available from Varga's website here: [PDF link](http://www.math.kent.edu/~varga/pub/paper_184.pdf).

In the left half-plane the zeros approach the semicircle $|z| = 1/e$, and, I showed in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3695) that those zeros which aren't too close to the imaginary axis satisfy

$$
|z| = \frac{1}{e} + \frac{\log n}{en} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

as $n \to \infty$.  To see this, take $a=0$, $b=1$, and $\varphi(z) = 1$ in the integral in $F(z)$ at the top of Section 3.  This makes $\xi = \mu = \nu = 0$, and the claim then comes from Theorem 3.1.a.

Comment: Thanks for the references.

Comment: Sure thing.  Feel free to ask if you have any questions.  I skipped lots of details, especially in the part about the circle $|z| = 1/e$.

Comment: Hmm, there is a typo in my paper.  This is a special case which is just outside of what I considered, so I have made a small correction to the last part this answer to reflect what I believe is true but I haven't worked through all the details.